# Any idea on this problem $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

This is a question in real analysis. I think it needs integral definition to prove, but not sure. Any idea is welcome.

> Let $f$ be a real valued uniform continuous function on $[0,\infty]$ such that
>   $$
> \lim \limits_{x\to\infty}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt
> $$
>   exists. Prove that
>   $$
> \lim \limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0
> $$

Comment: try mean value.

Comment: @user585440 ["Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post."](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates)

Comment: This might be one of the questions in analysis which is most often asked on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $F(x) = \int_0^xf.$ So we have $F'(x) + F(x) \to L$ at $\infty.$ Consider the function $e^xF(x).$

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help:
Let $F(x)$ be the integral of $f(x)$, so $E(x) = f(x)+F(x)-F(0)=exp(-x)*d[e^x*F(x)]/dx-F(0)$and $ lim_x E(x)=k$, for some $k$ constant, but this is equivalent to say that $lim$ of $exp(-x)*d[e^x*F(x)]dx=k+F(0)=C$; follows by intermediate theorem of Cauchy that exist a,b with $a<x<b$ such;
$d[e^x*F(x)]dx*exp[-x]=(e^a*F(a)-e^b*F(b))/(e^a-e^b)$, applying the limits with b tending to infinity and making some manipulations, we got $e^b*(F(b)-C)=e^a(F(a)-C)$ (this is a constant, lets say M); $e^b(F(b)-C)=M$,so $ F(b)-C=e^(-b)*M=0$ because b tends to infinity, we have $ F(b)=C$, and this is equivalent to $f(b)=0$.

Comment: http://paramanands.blogspot.ca/2012/08/two-problems-not-from-iit-jee.html#.VWEwUkYvnw0